# Accessing column IDs

Tags: jquery

I have a table with multiple rows. So,e of the rows are the table headers and have variable colspan.

I need to be able to get each column's id. I'm able to get row ID as well as the **w** cell id above. What I'm not sure is how to get is the id of the above that has a colspan.

```js
$(".cnt").each(function() {
  var ths = $(this);
  var rid = ths.closest("tr").find("th").attr("id"); // row label id
  var ind = ths.index();
  var wid = ths.closest("table").find(".w th:eq("+ind+")).attr("id"); // w col ID
  // var yid = ??? // year column id
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr class="y">
    <td></td>
    <th id="y2017" colspan="2">2017</th>
    <th id="y2018" colspan="3">2018</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="w">
    <td></td>
    <th id="w1">W1</th>
    <th id="w2">W2</th>
    <th id="w3">W3</th>
    <th id="w4">W4</th>
    <th id="w5">W5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="xyz">XYZ</th>
    <td class="cnt">23</td>
    <td class="cnt">55</td>
    <td class="cnt">4</td>
    <td class="cnt">55</td>
    <td class="cnt">323</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: you'd have to know that your column was the nth column in the table, and then work out, from the position and the colspan of each th, which th would span that column

Comment: I already get each column's index value: ths.index() I guess I need to keep summing up columns above, taking into consideration colspans and if the current index within the sum - grab ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way is to iterate a first time on the spanned row and build an array to link again the id for each column based on colspan value. You can also speed up your script by fetching week row content only once.

```js
var years = [];
var weeks = $("table").find('tr.w').children();

// Iteration on year row to build years array
$("table").find('tr.y').children().each(function(index) {
  let colspan = $(this).attr('colspan') || 1;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < colspan; i++) {
    years.push(this.id);
  }
});

$(".cnt").each(function(index) {
  let weekId, yearId;
  let rowId = $(this).parent().find('th').attr('id');
  
  weekId = weeks[index + 1].id;
  yearId = years[index + 1];
  console.log(this.innerHTML, rowId, weekId, yearId);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr class="y">
    <td></td>
    <th id="y2017" colspan="2">2017</th>
    <th id="y2018" colspan="3">2018</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="w">
    <td></td>
    <th id="w1">W1</th>
    <th id="w2">W2</th>
    <th id="w3">W3</th>
    <th id="w4">W4</th>
    <th id="w5">W5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="xyz">XYZ</th>
    <td class="cnt">23</td>
    <td class="cnt">55</td>
    <td class="cnt">4</td>
    <td class="cnt">55</td>
    <td class="cnt">323</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Map an array on page load that goes through those cells pushing id to array for each column it spans.

Then use index of data cells to access correct one

```js
var colIds = []

$('tr.y').children().each(function(){
   var colspan = +($(this).attr('colspan') || 1);
   var id = this.id || '';
   while(colspan){
      colIds.push(id);
      colspan--
   } 
});

// example getting values by cell index to display as text for this demo
$('.cnt').text(function(_,txt){
  return txt + ' - ' + colIds[$(this).index()]
})

console.log('colIds', JSON.stringify(colIds))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr class="y">
      <td></td>
      <th id="y2017" colspan="2">2017</th>
      <th id="y2018" colspan="3">2018</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="w">
      <td></td>
      <th id="w1">W1</th>
      <th id="w2">W2</th>
      <th id="w3">W3</th>
      <th id="w4">W4</th>
      <th id="w5">W5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="xyz">XYZ</th>
      <td class="cnt">23</td>
      <td class="cnt">55</td>
      <td class="cnt">4</td>
      <td class="cnt">55</td>
      <td class="cnt">323</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```